# Unable to restart rsyslog service using "sudo systemctl restart rsyslogd"

Tags: syslog, rsyslog

I am not able to restart `rsyslog service` using systemctl:

```
sudo systemctl restart rsyslogd.
```

I keep getting the time out error message.

Comment: Edit your question and include the output of `sudo systemctl status rsyslogd`